# MSSQL Ubuntu Unexpected call to legacy ABI

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu

We recently had a Ubuntu 16.04 server loose power. After restarting the server I noticed that MSSQL Server was no longer running due to a an error `Unexpected call to legacy ABI.` After researching for hours I could not solve the issue.

I then uninstalled MSSQL Server fully and reinstalled it. I went through the configure prompts although when choosing version (SQL Server Express) it would give an error `ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8` I then solved that by doing the following 2 commands:

```
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Which solved that issue, although after entering the system admin passwords I get this error:

```
This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Wed Apr 15 21:46:52 2020
The following diagnostic information is available:

         Reason: 0x00000003
         Status: 0x00000000
        Message: Unexpected call to legacy ABI.
          Stack:
                 IP               Function
                 ---------------- --------------------------------------
                 0000561aed8a2ada std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > c
                 0000561aed8a25d9 std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > c
                 0000561aed7ea9ae std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > c?*??~
                 0000561aed848717 std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > c
        Process: 20452 - sqlservr
         Thread: 20454
    Instance Id: ae93b937-d981-4d99-b419-bff7970c8bfb
       Crash Id: 
    Build stamp: 79eb721ef02d0426160fe0ad320e7425f9d012fbe368753d2655c5bce25b1b3c
   Distribution: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
     Processors: 4
   Total Memory: 8239382528 bytes
      Timestamp: Wed Apr 15 21:46:52 2020
/opt/mssql/lib/mssql-conf/invokesqlservr.sh: line 15: 20451 Aborted                 (core dumped) sudo -EH -u mssql /bin/bash -c "$CMDLINE"
Setup has completed successfully. SQL Server is now starting.
```

And the service is in a failed state.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/32c2b50b-4000-4ddf-bd7a-6876ca22a213/problem-starting-mssql-service-on-linux?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade):

> Short answer: Try renaming /var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id to
> something else, and restart SQL Server.
>
> Rationale:
>
> I was running into this issue on Linux Mint. I started noticing the
> problem after having done a system update and a reboot.
>
> I tried reinstalling SQL Server 2017 (same error), upgrading to the
> preview of 2019 (same error), and removing all the packages and using
> Docker instead.
>
> I noticed that starting the Docker image actually started SQL Server
> normally (although with none of my databases since the data is stored
> inside the container by default). After starting the docker image with
> the "-v /var/opt/mssql:/var/opt/mssql" option telling it to utilize my
> existing databases, I got the exact same error about an Unexpected
> call to legacy ABI.
>
> I noticed that one of the first lines in the error said "sqlservr:
> Unable to read instance id from /var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id: No
> such file or directory (2)". I tried reading that file, and it
> actually DID exist.
>
> I moved the existing file out of the way: mv
> /var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id
> /var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id.bak Then started SQL Server again -
> and it worked.
>
> So - some sort of corruption in the instance_id file or something
> related to it? The original (corrupted?) file only had two lines,
> while the newly-regenerated file had three lines, the first of which
> is dash-separated value that was not present in the original file.
>
> I'm not certain if this will have lingering consequences for my
> databases (not a big deal for me, as it's just dev data) - but so far
> it appears to be functioning.

I have tried this under centos 7 and for me it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Try renaming `/var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id` to something else, and restart SQL Server.
It worked for me

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately this server was decommissioned 3 years ago so have no way to test.